# Define Coverage Bin in System Verilog using Incremental Values

Tags: code-coverage, system-verilog, bins, function-coverage

I am trying to define coverage using systemverilog for a large coverage area.  For example, I would like to define a coverage bin that starts at `24'h000000`, ends at `24'h001ff0`, and increments by `24'h000008`.  I have tried this so far; however, it does not compile.

```
bins scratchpad = {24'h000000:24'h000008:24'h001ff0};
```

This gives a syntax error: `syntax error: token is ':'`.

Is there a way to avoid having to explicitly write out all the coverage points?  I know that I can define a bin with `{24'h000000:24'h001ff0}`, but this contains points that I do not wish to include.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a `with` clause

`bins scratchpad[] = {[24'h000000:24'h001ff0]} with (item % 8 == 0);`

See http://go.mentor.com/ready-for-systemverilog-2012 for other options
and the [IEEE 1800-2012 LRM](https://standards.ieee.org/getieee/1800/download/1800-2012.pdf) section 19.5.1.1